# Is there any way i can populate entity based on months but excluding the first month each loops?

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-bigquery

i have a set of data sample like this

```
| id | month
| x  | jan
| x  | feb
| x  | mar
```

is there any way i can populate that sample to be like this?

```
| id | month | number
| x  | jan   | 1
| x  | feb   | 2
| x  | mar   | 3
| x  | feb   | 1
| x  | mar   | 2
| x  | mar   | 1
```

this work like union all but excluding the first month each loops

Comment: is it for BigQuery or PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 'jan' month, 1 pos UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'feb', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'mar', 3 
)
SELECT id, month, 
  pos - MIN(pos) OVER(PARTITION BY id, num) + 1 AS number
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, pos)) AS num
-- ORDER BY num
```

with output

```
Row id  month   number   
1   1   jan     1    
2   1   feb     2    
3   1   mar     3    
4   1   feb     1    
5   1   mar     2    
6   1   mar     1
```

In case if `pos` field is not explicitly available  - you can derive it as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 'jan' month UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'feb' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'mar'
), temp AS (
  SELECT id, month, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM PARSE_DATE('%b', month)) pos
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
SELECT id, month, 
  pos - MIN(pos) OVER(PARTITION BY id, num) + 1 AS number
FROM temp,
UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, pos)) AS num
-- ORDER BY num
```

with  the same final  output

Comment: thanks man, it works for me. but, still it's hard to understand the logic behind it

Comment: i will get back later in a day (when time allows) with some explanations :o) but meantime, try to get it by yourself by just simply playing with it  - to start add `num` and `pos` to SELECT output list so you will see then how `number` is calculated

Answer (score 0):

If the table name is samples, you could try this recursive CTE:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT id
         , month
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id, month) number
    FROM samples
    union ALL
    SELECT id
         , month
         , nr-1
    FROM cte
    where nr>1
)
SELECT 
    id
    ,month
    ,number
FROM cte
```

First we number the rows using ROW_NUMBER(), then we use a recursive CTE to first return all rows, then return alle rows with row number>1, reducing the row number by 1, this runs for the same number of iterations as the original number of rows.

Comment: the "from cte" inside the CTE is unrecognized, it says Table name "cte" missing dataset while no default dataset is set in the request.

Answer (score 0):

```
with data as (
    select id, "month",
        case "month"
            when 'jan' then 1 when 'feb' then 2 when 'mar' then 3 when 'apr' then 4
            when 'may' then 5 when 'jun' then 6 when 'jul' then 7 when 'aug' then 8
            when 'sep' then 9 when 'oct' then 10 when 'nov' then 11 when 'dec' then 12
        end as mm
    from T
)
select d1.id, d1."month", row_number() over (partition by d1.id order by d1.mm) as nun
from data d1 cross apply data d2
where d1.mm <= d2.mm
```